# raise ValueError("x and y must be the same size") ValueError: x and y must be the same size

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

im currently doing the andrew ng machine learning course and trying to reproduce data and visualization from the course on my own in python spyder.
i have a small array of data which looks like this:

```
 [['Size' 'Bedrooms' 'Floors' 'Age Home' 'Price']
  ['952' '2' '1' '65' '271.5']
 ['1244' '3' '2' '64' '232']
  ['1974' '3' '2' '17' '509.8']]
```

i want to plot the Size, Bedrooms, Floors and Age Home on the x-axis compared to the price on the y-axis:

```
 arr = np.loadtxt(r"", delimiter=",", dtype=str)

 x_train = arr[1:, 2]
 y_train = arr[1:, 4]
 x_features = ["Size","Bedrooms","Floors","Age Home"]

 print(x_train)
print(y_train)

fig,ax=plt.subplots(1, 4, figsize=(12, 3), sharey=True)
for i in range(len(ax)):
ax[i].scatter(x_train[1: i],y_train)
ax[i].set_xlabel(x_features[i])
ax[0].set_ylabel("Price (1000's)")
plt.show()
```

i keep getting this error:
raise ValueError("x and y must be the same size")

ValueError: x and y must be the same size

pls help!

```
x_train = arr[1:, 2]
y_train = arr[1:, 4]
x_features = ["Szie","Bedrooms","Floors","Age Home"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what kind of output you expect.
I am assuming you want to have 5 axes, all showing some price following different arrays with labels.

[image]

The above image is produced with

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr = [
    ["Size", "Bedrooms", "Floors", "Age Home", "Price"],
    ["952", "2", "1", "65", "271.5"],
    ["1244", "3", "2", "64", "232"],
    ["1974", "3", "2", "17", "509.8"],
]

x_start = 1
x_train = arr[x_start:2]
y_start = 1
y_train = arr[y_start:]
x_features = ["Size", "Bedrooms", "Floors", "Age Home", "Price"]

print(x_train)
print(y_train)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 5, figsize=(12, 3), sharey=True)
for i, ax in enumerate(axs):
    for j, xs in enumerate(x_train, x_start):
        for k, ys in enumerate(y_train, y_start):
            ax.scatter([float(x) for x in xs], [float(y) for y in ys], label=f"x,y={j},{k}")
            ax.set_xlabel(x_features[i])

axs[0].set_ylabel("Price (1000's)")
axs[0].legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I am assuming the error you got originates mainly from mixing up strings with floats.
Strings of different lengths have different sizes.
Trying to plot them can result in `ValueError: x and y must be the same size`.
I converted the array to floats at plot-time, which is not good practice, I would say.

Also, all the plots are the same. They do not give different insights in the data.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/R2VzuKa i wanted it to look like this